# AddFeatures to an ArcGIS Online Feature Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

Is it possible to add and delete features from an ArcGIS Online-hosted feature service?

I'm able to do this with services hosted on our ArcGIS Server ([example here](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/SanFrancisco/311Incidents/FeatureServer/0/addFeatures)), but don't see the option under "Supported Operations" when looking at the REST endpoint for an AGOL-hosted feature service ([example here](http://services.arcgis.com/pwNwIGBE7M7VOXjQ/ArcGIS/rest/services/Buffer%20of%20Locations/FeatureServer/0)).

I understand that few people use both ArcGIS Server and ArcGIS Online, but our client is a heavy AGOL user and would like to store all their data in the platform instead of our ArcGIS Server.

If this isn't available, is it part of the roadmap for ArcGIS Online development? It seems strange that the REST endpoint is different from that made available from ArcGIS Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AddFeatures](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Add_Features/02r30000010m000000/) is an endpoint on feature services in both local Server and hosted Portal (arcgis.com)

You can see from this [blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/10/07/using-python-to-push-updates-to-a-hosted-feature-service-from-an-external-source/) and [associated script](https://github.com/arcpy/AutomaticUpdatesIntoFeatureService/blob/master/UpdatePointFromExternalAPI.py) that I call both addFeautres and updateFeatures.
You'll only see the addFeatures/updateFeautes/deleteFeatures, etc endpoints on the REST page if you have editing turned on for that service. If editing has NOT been enabled, you don't see the endpoints. You can still call them as long as you're authenticated (passing a token) admin on the org or the service owner itself.

Comment: This is great-- thanks so much @KHibma. I'd selected 'add layer to map with editing enabled', but hadn't formally enabled editing using the Edit dropdown. 

Is there a way to expose this addFeatures functionality to only credentialed users, but share a public map service of the same data? I can accomplish this using ArcGIS Server, but not sure if this is possible in AGOL. Thanks!

Comment: Check this out - https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-hosted-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_FFEC223155964B2195C03F43BEC4D2B9

Comment: Thanks for your help! Privileges is definitely what I want to get into, but it looks like that only governs feature services shared within an organization, not publicly. According to [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57918/arcgis-online-public-viewers-and-private-editors), security-through-obscurity is possible, but if one wants to actually secure the feature service, ArcGIS Server is required. Is that your understanding as well?

Comment: I'm going to use the script you've published [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/01/24/updating-your-hosted-feature-service-for-10-2/) to overwrite the entire feature service and republish. Thanks for putting that together-- super helpful.

Comment: Sorry, not sure about the AGS requirement to secure a FS for the workflow you describe